# handler function for local push notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to call/invoke a particular function when a local push notification is received by a device? It seems like there must be some way to do so, but I am having trouble finding information about it. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to do this when your app is in the foreground or in the background?

Comment: I'd like to do the same thing whether it's in the foreground or the background.

Comment: I just figured out how to respond to them in the foreground (willPresent function in AppDelegate). But the background isn't working--I thought that didReceive should do the trick, but it hasn't!

Comment: didReceive is only for remote notifications. Your app does not execute any code when a local notification is delivered while it is in the background.

Comment: Aw, that's so sad. Are there any workarounds you can think of? I was thinking of setting an NSTimer so that, when the push notifications some, the timer also causes my CloudKit update to simultaneously happen. Do you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: NSTimer doesn't fire in the background; see my comment on your other question.